# Sublime Text won't work on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, ubuntu-11.10

I used the PPA repository, and followed the instructions exactly to install sublime text. However, when I try to open it from Applications, I get a "This build of Sublime Text 2 has expired" message.

I tried removing it and reinstalling, but it didn't change anything. I also tried manually downloading the files from the sublimetext website, but I have no idea how to actually open the program or install it; it's just a bunch of files and python scripts in a sublime_text_2 directory.

I'm sure a lot of this has to do with me being an ubuntu noob, but I can't find any posts of people having trouble with the PPA install. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you posting this on stack overflow? What has this got to do with programming?

Comment: Whupps, meant to vote to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd highly recommend using [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3), as it is just as stable as ST2, and includes a number of new features. Additionally, more and more plugins from [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) (install it as soon as you have ST up and running) only work with ST3. Also, why are you still running Ubuntu 11.10? You really should [upgrade](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade) - 14.04 is the current LTS version, 14.10 is the current working version, and 15.04 will be out next month.

To install, download the `.deb` file for your version of Ubuntu (32- or 64-bit) from the link above. In Terminal, change to your Downloads directory and run

`sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3065_XXX.deb`

where ***`XXX`*** is `i386` for 32-bit, or `amd64` for 64-bit. Enter your password, and it should install automatically. To run it, open the applications search function and start typing `Sublime Text` and it should show up.